# Normalise data where every second row is a column header

Tags: python, pandas

I have a system where you manually input data, for example data about people. Some fields are mandatory but majority are optional. When the data is outputted it doesn't normalise the data but structures it so that the first row are the field headers you've populated, and the second row the data.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
data = [
    
    ['Name', 'Age', 'Eye_Colour', 'Height', 'Hair Colour', 'Kids', 'Job', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    ['John', '30', 'Brown', '130', 'Brown', 2, 'IT', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    ['Name', 'Age', 'Eye_Colour', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    ['Alex', 33, 'Blue', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    ['Name', 'Surname', 'Eye_Colour', 'Middlename', 'Nationality', 'Age', 'Height', 'Hair Colour', 'Kids', 'Job', 'Salary'],
    ['Mary', 'Smith', 'Green', 'Rose', 'UK', '50', 130, 'Black', 'None', 'Sales', 120000], 
    ['Name', 'Surname', 'Eye_Colour', 'Middlename', 'Nationality', 'Age','Salary', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    ['Sarah', 'Short', 'Green', 'Susie', 'Americann', 22, 25000, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
]

joined_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11, 12, 13, 14])
```

I need to

1. Normalise the data entirely. So this would mean the 5th row, or the column headers for `Mary`, would be the column headers for the whole dataframe. And the other entries would align up to the correct headings.
2. separate the data into data frames based on a matching variable, in this case `Eye_Colour`. What that looks like here is 3 data frames, one each for for `Brown`, `Blue`, and `Green`. Each of these would have a different number of column headers. The dataframe for `Blue` would only have 3 columns. `Eye_Colour` is a mandatory field and is always in the same place, ie always be returned with `joined_data[3]`

I have started on 2) by removing the final 3 columns through `dropna(axis = 1, how = 'all')`, where there is no data at all for any rows. Then filtering on `Eye_Colour` and also taking the row above

```py
joined_data_mask = ((joined_data[3] == 'Green') | (joined_data[3].shift(-1) == 'Green') )
joined_data[joined_data_mask]
```

Which returns data for `Green`. My next thought was to calculate the row length excl Nans (which may be different for each person). I'd then group by matching ones and separate these into different data frames. I'd then take the df with the most column headers, use that as my template and append all the others to it.

I think I could use this solution to solve problem 1), but I am not sure.

The data I'm dealing with is large - about 300 columns and > 150000 rows. There are also about 300 types of 'eye_colour', so efficiency is reasonably important. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If think separating dataframes by going through `data` 2 by 2 is the right approach. I don't understand the bit about matching variables though.

`pd.concat` will concatenate the dataframes and align columns. You'll have to remove nan values while creating the dataframes:

```
pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame(
            [[x for x in data[i+1] if str(x)!='nan']], 
            columns = [x for x in data[i] if str(x)!='nan'])
        for i in range(0, len(data), 2)])
        .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    Name Age Eye_Colour Height Hair Colour  Kids    Job Surname Middlename Nationality    Salary
0   John  30      Brown    130       Brown     2     IT     NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN
1   Alex  33       Blue    NaN         NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN        NaN         NaN       NaN
2   Mary  50      Green    130       Black  None  Sales   Smith       Rose          UK  120000.0
3  Sarah  22      Green    NaN         NaN   NaN    NaN   Short      Susie   Americann   25000.0
```

Comment: This returns the error  `AssertionError: 178 columns passed, passed data had 162 columns`. I'm not sure where this is coming from as if there is a column header then there should be a corresponding value for each entry.

Comment: Are you trying on another data than the one you posted? If so please post an excerpt. I guess there are other invalid values than `np.nan` causing problems. or maybe a length mismatch between `data[i]` and `data[i+1]`

Comment: Yes using a different dataset - unfortunately it is confidential so I can't share it. How would you identify invalid values other than Nan (in the original dataset it is just blank)?

Comment: inside a loop `for i in range(0, len(data), 2)`, print i and build the df `df=pd.DataFrame([[x for x in data[i+1] if str(x)!='nan']], columns = [x for x in data[i] if str(x)!='nan'])` the last printed i value will give you the line where the error occurs

Comment: I just understood what you meant with "just blank". Try replacing `str(x)!='nan'` with `str(x)!=''` or `str(x)!='None'`. It's not clear what your source data is or how you read it

Comment: Yes that seems to have worked better. I'm not getting the issue `AttributionError: NoneType has no attribute 'is_extension'`. SO suggests this could be caused by duplicate column headers. I tried amending the code to include: `.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]` after `pd.DataFrame()`
But this didn't work. Error `Index Error('indices are out of bounds`

Comment: Post two incriminated lines (edit them to hide confidential information) so that we can reproduce the problem